# Data Storage in MySql

Tags: mysql

I have loaded 20 million records in Mysql, however I need to know where the data is located and memory allocated for it.

I went through one of the blog and tried out the below query where I found result of the data path location.

> show variables like 'datadir';

Can someone provide me the details where I can figure out the memory allocated to it?

Added screenshot below which are having tables with extension of ".frm" with a size around 9kb .

[screenshot for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mUXN.png)

Comment: The location isn't fixed; you should check out your Server MySQL preferences / settings to see where data is actually stored on the disc.

Comment: I am currently using MySQL Workbench 6.3

Comment: Well look in the preferences/setting of either Workbench or the MySQL install,......